# Visualizing all tag values

Tags: grafana, influxdb, grafana-variable

I'm looking for a way to visualize all the available values for one specific tag ("pair" in the picture)
I understand that I can manually create individually, but I'm not sure if there's a better for this

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the tag of interest.

So, here you can insert "tag(pair)" to the GROUP BY part. Remove it from the where clause as well.